# Add an item among those displayed in a Views block that links to the item creation page

Tags: views

**The goal:**

[image]

How do I add the "Add new project" item as the first among the other projects shown in the Views block? The content would link to the project creation page (node/add/project) ?

Please suggest other methods/alternatives if this is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header to the view and style it to fit your needs.

You can chose between *rendered entity: custom menu link* or just add a *textarea* and enter your link. The first option might be better because it provides an access check.

You might need to customize some of the fields HTML within the fields style settings to make this work.